# What park has the most rides: Disneyland Park or Disney California Adventure Park in the US?

Tags: los-angeles, disney

Compared to Disneyland Paris, in the USA both Disney parks seem to have more activities. I'm planning to buy 1-Day Ticket for Disneyland Park or Disney California Adventure Park depending on the number of rides each offers.

I would like to know what park has the most roller coaster rides or any other adventurous activities which can be enjoyed by an adult too.

Comment: If you want roller coasters, [Six Flags: Magic Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Flags_Magic_Mountain) is probably a more appropriate park.

Answer (score 4):

Simply going by the number of attractions (rides, shows, etc...), [Disneyland has 54](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disneyland_attractions) while [California Adventure has 34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_California_Adventure_attractions). These range from fast roller coasters to train rides.

However, there is no way you're going to be able to do everything, or even get close, in one day. I'd recommend that you review the list of attractions and decide what interests you personally. Some people get really obsessive with their planning, even subscribing to sites like [touringplans.com](https://touringplans.com/walt-disney-world/touring-plans) (which has lots of free content as well) and mapping out exactly what they want to do, while others will just wander and go for what interests them, but there are a number of sites that provide details of the attractions and make suggestions, including [Disney's own site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt36285JHWAhVBx1QKHZ9sDGcQFgh8MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdisneyland.disney.go.com%2Fattractions%2F&usg=AFQjCNFCTB3CM7Yx0T1GIPK61FclgRYFug) and [AllEars.net](http://allears.net/dlr/dlresort.htm), which has detailed information on every attraction and lots of planning advice.

You might also find the Quora question [Which is better: Disneyland or California Adventure?](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-better-Disneyland-or-California-Adventure) useful for some general differences between the parks.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one day at Disneyland Resort and do not expect to return for a very long time, or ever :(, **go to Disneyland**.

The Disney experience is not about rides.  If rides are what you want, Knott's Berry Farm is a better choice.  **Disneyland itself is the destination and experience.**

Disney Classics: Small World, Pirates of the Caribbean, The Haunted Mansion, The Jungle Cruise

Thrills: Indiana Jones, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain.

To Enjoy: The Disneyland Railroad, Mark Twain Riverboat, Fantasmic.

Definitely use **FastPass and MaxPass**.  It's worth it for a one day trip.  The one 'adult' consideration between the parks is that alcohol is only served at DCA and you are presumably not a member of Club 33.

Also, *very important*, there are **6** Disney parks in the United States. ;)

Source: Experience, I've been to every Disney park worldwide, multiple times.

Comment: Yes, and what Zach Lipton said in his answer is important as well: there is no way you are going to be able to do everything in either park in one day, even if there were no lines at all (spoiler alert: there are lines).